# Playing Mp3 file using C++ program

Tags: c++, mp3

I am a beginner in C++. I want to make a program that can play an mp3 file. ***" I don't want to use any kind of pre-programmed libraries, until they are C++ own libraries like #include <string> or <conio.h>"***. I want to get an idea, what I have to do to play it using purely c++. I haven't learnt SDL and things like that so please don't direct me to use it and don't tell me to use FMod libraries and things like that and no instructions about GUI please.. Thanks for your precious help..

Comment: @Alfred: The C++ standard library is just bare basics that are used in every type of project.  If you're not dealing with basics, you have to link against an actual library of some sort.  C++ can't even delete a file without making calls to the OS's libraries.

Comment: @Alfred: also, mp3's are amazingly complicated.  I've been programming for many years and have no clue how to load one myself.  Try a bitmap instead.

Answer (score 6):

C++ does not provide any audio abstraction features. You will have to write platform specific code (and probably use some libraries for accessing the audio of your platform). The easiest thing is to use some kind of library like sdl.

For the future please describe what you tried and what your current problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Though technically written in C, this link showcases what it is you want - it plays an MP3 using the Windows Media Player API.  As you can see, the code gets quite tedious and somewhat complicated.  This is why even experienced developers usually reach for a library (such as FMOD, OpenAL, etc...) when it comes to playing sounds.

http://code4k.blogspot.com/2010/05/playing-mp3-in-c-using-plain-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Playing mp3 files in pure c++ is much too complicated for an beginner. Also there are a lot of MP3-related patents - so be carefull what youre planning to do! You need to understand the whole file format (see here: http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=MP3) to decode an MP3 File (easier would be i.e. wav) with filestreams and use the audiohardware for output. That is also plattform dependend so you need to specify a plattform that you want to use...

Seriously if you need to ask this kind of questions, better use an library or anything like that.